# How to read system.net/mailSettings/smtp from Web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, smtp, sendmail

This is my `web.config` mail settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="smthg@smthg.net">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" port="587" userName="smthg@smthg.net" password="123456"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

and here's how I try to read the values from `web.config`

```
 var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
 var credential = new System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection().Network;

 string strHost = smtp.Host;
 int port = smtp.Port;
 string strUserName = credential.UserName;
 string strFromPass = credential.Password;
```

But credentials are always null. How can i access these values?

Answer (score 115):

Since no answer has been accepted, and none of the others worked for me:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;
// snip...
var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
string username = smtpSection.Network.UserName;
```

Comment: This is the better answer

Comment: This does not work for me. Every time I am getting null.. The code is same as here.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 38):

It is not necessary to use the `ConfigurationManager`and get the values manually. Simply instantiating an `SmtpClient` is sufficient.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

This is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> This constructor initializes the Host, Credentials, and Port properties for the new SmtpClient by using the settings in the application or machine configuration files.

Scott Guthrie wrote a small [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) on that some time ago.

Comment: Though that doesn't tell you if, for instance, [`SpecifiedPickupDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.configuration.smtpsection.specifiedpickupdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) is being used -- in which case you might need to turn `EnableSSL` off in your SMTP init code to avoid 'SSL must not be enabled for pickup-directory delivery methods.'. 2¢, etc...

Answer (score 9):

By using the configuration, the following line:

```
var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
```

Will use the configured values - you don't need to access and assign them again.

---

As for the `null` values - you are trying accessing the configuration values incorrectly. You are just creating an empty `SmtpSection` instead of reading it from configuration.

```
var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("<the section name>");
var credentials == smtpSection.Network;
```

Comment: If you wanted to say it;

 var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
 string strUserName = smtp .UserName;
 string strFromPass = smtp .Password;

I can't access like this.

Comment: @nermik - I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I just want to access UserName and Password from web.config like  Host and port.

Comment: var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("<the section name>");
I used it but still null.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you have defaultCredentials="true" set you will have the credentials = null as you are not using them.

Does the email Send when you  call the .Send method?

So

This is my web config mail settings:

```xml
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="smthg@smthg.net">
         <network defaultCredentials="false" host="localhost" port="587"
            userName="smthg@smthg.net" password="123456"/>
      </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and this is cs

```cs
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

string smtpDetails =
    @"
    DeliveryMethod = {0},
    Host = {1},
    PickupDirectoryLocation = {2},
    Port = {3},
    TargetName = {4},
    UseDefaultCredentials = {5}";

Console.WriteLine(smtpDetails,
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod.ToString(),
    smtpClient.Host,
    smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation == null
        ? "Not Set"
        : smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation.ToString(),
    smtpClient.Port,
    smtpClient.TargetName,
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials.ToString)
);
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue here. The OP is creating a new `SmtpSection` instead of reading it from the configuration.

Comment: Emmh just seen that.. so if you just call SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); it should read the condig settings for you but I'm nearly sure I also remember something around the default credentitals being true... I'll check it

Comment: Yes if you use default credentials the Username and pwd should be empty. As Oded said... now create a new credential... just instantite your SmtpClient like SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();  and check the settings

Comment: ok so to use the UserName and Pwd from your config... set.. network defaultCredentials="false"

Answer (score 3):

```
            //You can access the network credentials in the following way.
            //Read the SmtpClient section from the config file    
            var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            //Cast the newtwork credentials in to the NetworkCredential class and use it .
            var credential = (System.Net.NetworkCredential)smtp.Credentials;
            string strHost = smtp.Host;
            int port = smtp.Port;
            string strUserName = credential.UserName;
            string strFromPass = credential.Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have reference to System.Net in your application

Answer (score -1):

Set defaultCredentials="false", because when it's set to true, no credentials are used.